# necessity to give delay to adc

Tags: arduino, adc

I was trying to send analog signals from **arduino** to the computer by the serial port.For getting the maximum samples of my input analog signals,I put my baudrate to the maximum limit.The code is as given

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
 void loop()

{
  int a=analogRead(A0);
   Serial.println(a);
   delay(1);
}
```

This program works well for my signals with very low frequency.but at higher frequency signals,there is still arising a problem of aliasing.I tried decreasing the delay.i got more samples When i did this but some of my digital values that I got could not be used,that is,some of the wrong digital values were like **353?12** and so on.Is it manda to give minimum delay of 1 ms to the **ADC**??Or is there any way that i can Increase my samplestory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into an issue with the default prescaler setting in arduino. The default setup will only get less than 10 samples per millisecond.

You can certainly get faster reads from your ADC if you want to play with some of the underlying settings:
www.microsmart.co.za/technical/2014/03/01/advanced-arduino-adc/
has a good write up on the subject. They got it running at 50 samples per millisecond with some tweaking.

The other option is to get an ADC chip which will run faster for you. Search sparkfun for "mcp3002". No tweaking of your arduino required since it uses spi input.

Comment: thanks a lot.it worked.but i need more samples.i have heard that **analogRead** reads the input quite slowly and that using registers to access data speeds it up.can u suggest about how can i do it??

Comment: What is your sample rate right now? What is your target?

Comment: i think 50 samples.i hav set my prescaler to 16 now.actually i m try to sample my signals and plot them to obtain the waveform,just like an osciloscope.but whenever i go above 100 hertz,i get inadequate samples

Comment: Just so I can give you good help: How comfortable are you with c programming, binary manipulation and byte variables? Don't worry if you have no experience I will try to explain everything I'm doing as I go if needed.

Comment: well i know the basics of c programming but i have not gone much to the depths .so can i increase my sampling speed if i go to binary level?please do help me

Comment: if u dont mind,could you please give u mail id so that i can directly communicate with u during my programming

Comment: I'll give it a go when i get to my computer (on my phone right now). Also, you said 50 samples. Is that per second or per millisecond?

Comment: per millisecond.as per the write up which u had suggested me

Comment: mail me: so at refinebs dot ca

Comment: That sample rate is pretty good. If anything will speed it up it would be the digitalread but not sure how much more you can squeeze out of the onboard ADC

Comment: I meant to say analogRead(). There is a lot of crap in there but it looks like most of it is fairly quick. We'll see if there is something we can pull out

Comment: okay thank u.i will mail u tomorrow. isnt your mail so@refinebs.ca

Comment: yes that's it. Also, while you are waiting I highly recommend you go on over to humanharddrive's youtube channel and look up the series he did on AVR-C. You wont need the specific ADC stuff (we don't need to build it ourselves to get this going I don't think) but if you understand what we can play with, it might help.

Comment: I have sent you a mail.Kindly look into the matter